# phonegap 3 android backbutton not working

Tags: android, cordova

I am using phonegap 3.0 / android with inappbrowser plugin. When I press back button, display
goes to the gray background page (probably the one before loading the browser).
I tried catching the backbutton event. Strange thing, the very first event is not caught I believe. I get the second time and so on (I see the alert) but seems as if it is too late.
I need backbutton to behave in the default fashion.. go back in browser one page at a time.

Here is the relevant part of the script:

```
function bButton () {
  alert('back pressed');
}

function deviceReady () {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", bButton, true);
    var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=no');
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () { deviceReady(); },
                          false);
```

Any help is appreciated ..

Answer (score 3):

Just add this to your config.xml:

```
<feature name="App">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
</feature>
```

Comment: This seems to be an issue with 3.*. I am using 3.1 and yet I had to manually add this mapping. It would help if anyone knows the git repo link for this. Or may be the device plugin should add this mapping and is not doing so.

Comment: I'm using Icenium on cordova version 3.0 and this fixed it for me. Why I needed to do it I don't know :/

Answer (score 0):

```
var ref;
function bButton () {
  ref.close();
   alert('back pressed');
}
function deviceReady () {
   document.addEventListener("backbutton", bButton, true);
   ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=no');
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue but I found out today that if you accidentally bind a press event more than once to your inappbrowser launch button your backbutton may not work.

```
$('#inappbrowser_button').bind('touchstart',function(){
    window.open('your_url','_blank');
});
```

With the above my backbutton wouldn't work (in Android). It was till I changed it to the following that the backbutton started working again:

```
$('#inappbrowser_button')
.unbind('touchstart')
.bind('touchstart',function(){
    window.open('your_url','_blank');
});
```

There may be something bigger/more important at play there but that's at least what my issue with the Android (inAppBrowser) backbutton not working sometimes.